# Test the maxlength property of a text field using protractor in angular js app

Tags: angularjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a text field. I want to test whether the characters entered are less than 15 in it. Please find the below code.

```
<div input-container placeholder="fname">
   <input fr-validate type="text" class="form-control border-radius-0" ng-maxlength="15" ng-model="fname" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you would need to use `getAttribute('value')` to get the input value, but it's not gonna work straight as @MrWoGu suggested. `element.getAttribute('value')` *returns a promise* and you need to resolve it, either explicitly:

```
element.getAttribute('value').then(function (value) {
    expect(value.length).toBeLessThan(15);
});
```

Or implicitly with `expect()` - it is patched to resolve promises. Now, the question is, what matcher to choose to check the string length. Here are the options (including matchers coming from [`jasmine-matchers`](https://github.com/JamieMason/Jasmine-Matchers) package):

```
expect(element.getAttribute('value')).toMatch(/.{1,14}/);
expect(element.getAttribute('value')).toBeShorterThan("012345678901234");
```

There is though probably a better way to solve it in one line with a single matcher. Making a [custom matcher](http://jasmine.github.io/2.3/custom_matcher.html) is also an option.

Answer (score 0):

In protractor you have to use getAttribute for textfields.

Just try this:

```
if (element.getAttribute('value').length < 15)
{
    // less than 15
}
```

Docs: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/faq.md#the-result-of-gettext-from-an-input-element-is-always-empty

Comment: This does not work. As alexce noted, getAttribute returns a promise.